# Como criar um "defnine" com argumentos indeterminados?

Tags: c++

Eu vi em algum lugar a algum tempo que isso era possível, e agora eu preciso implementar isso pra facilitar a leitura do código.

É o seguinte :

```
void A::adicionarTodos () {
    lista.adicionar(A1::id);
    lista.adicionar(A2::id);
    [etc...]
    lista.adicionar(An::id);
}
```

Algumas classe eu tenho que por dezenas de linhas, fica realmente confuso, meu objetivo é fazer um define simples assim :

```
implementar(A,A1,A2, [ETC...],An);
```

Esses argumentos todos são nomes de classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com "define" acho que não dá para fazer, mas com "variadic templates" é possível, embora seja algo complicado.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void adicionar(int i)
{
   cout << "* adicionando " << i << '\n';
}

void adicionarTodos()
{
}

template <typename A1, typename ... As >
void adicionarTodos(A1 a1, As... as)
{
   adicionar(a1);
   adicionarTodos(as...);
}

int main()
{
   adicionarTodos(1);
   adicionarTodos(2, 3);
   adicionarTodos(4, 5, 6);
}
```

Resultado:

```
* adicionando 1
* adicionando 2
* adicionando 3
* adicionando 4
* adicionando 5
* adicionando 6
```

Adicionado depois: acho que a solução acima na verdade não responde à pergunta feita. Pesquisei um pouco mais, e baseado nesta resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38776200/1856694) do SOen criei uma outra solução,que acho mais adequada como resposta:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X1 { enum {  i = 1 }; };
struct X2 { enum {  i = 2 }; };
struct X3 { enum {  i = 3 }; };
struct X4 { enum {  i = 4 }; };
struct X5 { enum {  i = 5 }; };
struct X6 { enum {  i = 6 }; };

// condicao de parada do template
template <int i=0> void adicionarTodos() { }

template <typename A1, typename ... As>
void adicionarTodos()
{
   cout << "* adicionando " << A1::i << '\n';
   adicionarTodos<As...>();
}

int main()
{
   adicionarTodos<X1>();
   adicionarTodos<X2,X3>();
   adicionarTodos<X4,X5,X6>();
}
```

Comment: cara, isso  é tipo uma trapaça ! muito bom isso ! Ele vai perder de 1 por 1 e no final faz o método sem template

Comment: não é trapaça, é assim que se usa mesmo...veja outra maneira que coloquei